# Enterprise Admin can't use MDT?

Tags: windows, deployment, permissions, active-directory, mdt

Running a rather large network with an MDT deployment server. I currently have another person who works with me registered as a 'Enterprise Administrator'. Part of his job is imaging machines. Currently I have it set so that devices that need imaging are set as 'Pending' until allowed within Windows Deployment Services.

When the EAdmin tries to open the 'pending devices' tab of WDS, he gets an access is denied message.

How do I go about delegating permissions to use WDS to this user?

(Server 2012)

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

Needed to add the user in to the LOCAL administrator's group for the deployment server.